# wp_update_user doesn't update and update_user_meta does

Tags: user-meta

I'm building user profile page where users could update their profile on the front-end. User profile is extended with a few custom fields, like 'Twitter', 'Facebook' and 'City'.

The following code successfully updates all user details except the `dCity`:

```
$user_fields = array(
 'ID'           => $current_user->ID,
 'nickname'     => esc_attr($_POST['nickname']),
 'first_name'   => esc_attr($_POST['first_name']),
 'last_name'    => esc_attr($_POST['last_name']),
 'display_name' => esc_attr($_POST['display_name']),
 'user_email'   => esc_attr($_POST['email']),
 'user_url'     => esc_attr($_POST['url']),
 'twitter'      => esc_attr($_POST['twitter']),
 'facebook'     => esc_attr($_POST['facebook']),
 'description'  => esc_attr($_POST['description']),
 'dCity'        => esc_attr($_POST['dCity'])
);

wp_update_user($user_fields) ;
```

I've tried to use `update_user_meta` to update `dCity` and it worked:

```
$user_fields = array(
 'ID'           => $current_user->ID,
 'nickname'     => esc_attr($_POST['nickname']),
 'first_name'   => esc_attr($_POST['first_name']),
 'last_name'    => esc_attr($_POST['last_name']),
 'display_name' => esc_attr($_POST['display_name']),
 'user_email'   => esc_attr($_POST['email']),
 'user_url'     => esc_attr($_POST['url']),
 'twitter'      => esc_attr($_POST['twitter']),
 'facebook'     => esc_attr($_POST['facebook']),
 'description'  => esc_attr($_POST['description'])
);

wp_update_user($user_fields);
update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'dCity', $_POST['dCity'] );
```

So problem solved, but I'm wondering why `wp_update_user` doesn't update all records? Am I doing something wrong?

In advance, thank you.

Comment: you can install the WP_DEBUG plugin and then dig into what's happening behind the scene, error messages (if any) and I think that will give you some clue about this strange scenario

Comment: I think it has something to do with how data is saved to wp database, there are two separated tables "wp_users" and "wp_usermeta".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### wp_update_user & metadata

[`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) updates records in the **_users* table. It isn't meant to update custom metadata in the **_usermeta* table.

Hence your "problem" is actually expected behavior.

The `$userdata` argument passed to [`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) can contain the following fields:

*ID, user_pass, user_login, user_nicename, user_url, user_email, display_name, nickname, first_name, last_name, description, rich_editing, user_registered, role, show_admin_bar_front*

Further it accepts metadata that is recognized as a "contact method". This it will save to the **_usermeta* table.

By default, those are *jabber*, *aim* & *yim*.

These can however be altered / appended to by means of the `'user_contactmethods'` filter. As for the question raised in the comments, that is likely how twitter & facebook metadata have been made saveable via [`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user).

Any additional metadata should be saved as such with the appropriate functions.

### How does it happen in the core?

This just as an aside:

[`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) calls `_get_additional_user_keys` which in turn calls `_wp_get_user_contactmethods`. The resulting metakeys are iterated over back in [`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) and if a value exists added to the **_usermeta* table via [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).

For reference, see [Line 1426 and after (as of 3.5.1) of */wp-includes/user.php*](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/user.php#L1426)

Comment: I am curious to know, in that case how his "twitter" and "facebook" fields are saved?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That makes sense, but I'm also curious how "twitter" and "facebook" fields are saved? Also Codex says `wp_update_user()` - This function updates a single user in the database. This update can contain multiple pieces of user metadata as an array. To update a single piece of user metadata, use `update_user_meta()` instead.

Comment: See the appended answer, @Hasin

Comment: As for the codex: I *might* be on the wrong track here and have missed the spot in the functions in question where arbitrary metadata is saved, but having read their source thoroughly, it is much more likely the codex page contains misleading info. The codex is neither complete nor always correct.

Comment: You are gold Johannes! Thank you for clarifying all the details.

Comment: @JohannesPille The codex is definitely incorrect, or rather provides a poor explanation of `wp_update_user`. This function has tripped me up in the past. It will allow you to update values that exist in both the `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables but only those values which are defined as default by WordPress, e.g. for usermeta -> `first_name, last_name, nickname, description, rich_editing, comment_shortcuts, admin_color, use_ssl, show_admin_bar_front` but not any custom-custom-field, if that isn't confusing enough to the end user.